# XMLNODE: how can i select this node with attribute in my xml

Tags: c#, xmldocument, xmlnode

I have an xml with the following structure

```
<student>
    <name fname="oliver">
    </name>
    <name fname="de">
    </name>
    <name fname="johnson">
    </name>
</student>
```

my code is like this:

//after loading into an xmldocument called xmlrecord

```
    XmlNode row = xmlRecord.SelectSingleNode("/student");
    student.fname = row.SelectSingleNode("name[fname]");
```

But its not returning anything. Pls what is the best way to select the fname='johnson' node?

Comment: That's kind of an odd structure for XML; having each part of a name as its own attribute on three separate `name` nodes seems redundant. Name parts are attributes of one name. If you have control over this XML, I would change it to `<student><name fname="..." mname="..." lname="..." /></student>`

Comment: no i dont have control over the xml

Answer (score 1):

You want the `fname` attribute of the first `<name>` element, so you should write:

```
student.fname = row.SelectSingleNode("name/@fname");
```

Comment: that didnt work...it gave an XPATH error:Expression must evaluate to a node-set.

Comment: It should return a node set consisting in a single item: the attribute node. The error you speak about can occur if there is a syntax error in the XPath expression, maybe you included my answer in a larger expression?

Comment: @oliverdejohnson, the expression should still work with your edited markup, it will match three attribute nodes but `SelectSingleNode()` will only return the first one. I suspect you're not telling us the whole story, and that namespaces may be involved. Can you update your question with your *exact* XML markup?

Comment: the point is that in my xml that node is not the first node...its somewhere in the middle of about 60 of such nodes

Comment: @oliverdejohnson, you will have to use another attribute as the determinator, then. Unless you have the index of the element you're looking for, in which case you can match it according to its `position()`.

Comment: how do i use the position() please?

Comment: @oliverdejohnson, for instance: `SelectSingleNode("name[position() = 42]/@fname")`. Note that values of `position()` are one-based.

Comment: thanks @frederic i finally got it working by doing `SelectSingleNode("name[fname=johnson]"`... basically just supplying the attribute value.tnks for helping me come to this realization.cheers